# How can I use pip3 with google colab?

Tags: python, pip, jupyter, google-colaboratory

```
%pip3 install --index-url=https://pypi.spotify.net/spotify/production confidence
```

results in this error:

```
UsageError: Line magic function `%pip3` not found.
```

How can I install a package with pip3 on google colab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `!` instead `%` in order to run bash commands

`!pip3 install --index-url=https://pypi.spotify.net/spotify/production confidence`

However you can simply use `pip` instead of `pip3`

Edit: as you see the url returns a ConnectTimeoutError because it is apparently broken. Maybe you want simply run

`!pip install spotify confidence` ?

Comment: The ! does make pip3 work. Unfortunately it still does not enable my install, as there must be a more fundamental barrier than just using pip3 vs pip. Thanks!

Comment: "!pip install spotify confidence" installs the spotify package, then the confidence package. Unfortunately this is not the confidence package that Spotify build, but another package that is unrelated.